# How to find the orientation/angle of a segment of a line

Tags: qgis

Is there a way of finding out the angle of a segment of a vector not just the whole vector

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact software in use, the units of the coordinate system of the data, and what you have tried. `atan2(dy,dx)` would be involved in Cartesian solutions; computing angle and backangle in geodetic space is far more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

**To estimate the orientation of a line segment:**

1. Turn on snapping to segment and vertex.

   [image]
2. Use the Angle measurement tool to measure the angle between the line segment and north.

   [image]

   Note: The accuracy of this method depends on how perfectly you orient the north segment of the angle measurement tool.

**To find the orientation of a line a specified distance from the start of the line:**

Use this expression in the Expression Builder. It will calculate the orientation of the line segment at the specified distance from the start point. Distance units are in the unit's of the layer's CRS.

```
 line_interpolate_angle( $geometry, distance)
```

You can use this expression in the Field Calculator to store the angle value as an attribute, or use it for data-defined labels as explained below.

**To label each segment of a line with the segment angle:**

Combine that expression with data-defined label placements. Define the x and y coordinates with these formulas (using the same distance value as for the angle calculation):

```
 x(line_interpolate_point( $geometry, distance))
 y(line_interpolate_point( $geometry, distance))
```

To label a line with multiple angle measurements at different distances, use rule-based labeling. Create a new rule for each distance.

Using conditional logic and additional formulas, set up rules to place one angle measurement in the middle of each segment of every line. These formulas will be useful:

- `num_points` - Returns the number of vertices in a geometry.
- `distance_to_vertex` - Returns the distance along the geometry to a specified vertex.

Define the angle for the first line segment using this formula:

```
 line_interpolate_angle($geometry, distance_to_vertex($geometry,1)/2)
```

Define the label placement x and y coordinates with these formulas:

```
 x(line_interpolate_point($geometry, distance_to_vertex($geometry,1)/2))
 y(line_interpolate_point($geometry, distance_to_vertex($geometry,1)/2))
```

For the second line segment, use `distance_to_vertex($geometry,2)/2` for the distance value.

Follow this pattern to create additional rules for as many vertices as the most complicated line geometry has.

Apply a filter to each rule so that label won't be displayed if the current line geometry doesn't have that many vertices. Eg, here's the filter expression for the second line segment:

```
num_points($geometry)>2
```